# React Fails to render new component after state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following fails to render the selected Component even when the state is updated. I assumed it might have to do with the shallow check react makes, however after forcing a re-render the page still shows the originally selected component and not the new component. The only way I got it to correctly function was by changing the activeService state to <></> then changing it to the correct Service Component. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AquireServices from "./AquireService";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";
import Service from "./Service";

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state=({
      services: {},
      activeService: <></>
    });
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try{
        let services = await AquireServices();
        this.setState({ services: services });
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
  }

  selectedField = async (field) => {
    let service = this.state.services[field];
    if(service){
      this.setState({ activeService: <Service props={service} /> });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Box sx={{ padding: 0, display: 'flex' }}>
        <Navigation selectFunction={this.selectedField.bind(this)}/>
        {this.state.activeService}
      </Box>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image: Initial]

[image: Displaying Correct Field]

[image: Displaying previous Field after state change]

Output after changes:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No no, you don't need to store a component and try to render it via the state object.

If you observe, the only thing that is changing when you select things in the `Navigation Box` is the `service` props.

So, instead of storing a whole component, you can just store the selected service's props. Then, you can pass that props directly to the `Service` component in `render()`, like this:

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state=({
      services: {},
      activeService: undefined
    });
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try{
        let services = await AquireServices();
        this.setState({ services: services });
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
  }

  selectedField = async (field) => {
    let service = this.state.services[field];
    if(service){
      this.setState({ activeService: service });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {activeService} = this.state;
    return(
      <Box sx={{ padding: 0, display: 'flex' }}>
        <Navigation selectFunction={this.selectedField.bind(this)}/>
        {activeService ? <Service props={activeService}> : undefined}
      </Box>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I made the changes shown, I am still having an issue where only the first Component is rendered. I added some console logs and it appears that activeState is being correctly changed and retrieved however, the log statements in the Service constructor are only output on the first Component and not when I attempt to select the other one. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am assuming the bug is in the `Navigation` component -- maybe the `props.selectFunction` is not properly accessed there. So that's why the changes are not reflecting properly.

Comment: I added the console logs to my question, it shows that activeState is being correctly set and that for some reason the second Service component is never created as the log is not output. Thanks for your help so far!